# how to reference value from above row?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm developing an algorithm in r (with data.tables) and I need to compare a value from one of the columns with the value from the row above.

I've tried shifting/lead/lag the column but it does not work as I imagine

`input_csv[, newCol:= ifelse(input_csv[, Col] > shift(newCol, 1L, type="shift") + tolerance * shift(newCol, 1L, type="shift")), input_csv[, Col], shift(newCol, 1L, type="shift"))]`

What I want to achive would look like

```
Col         NewCol
116.1423    116.1423
116.1431    116.1423
116.1431    116.1423
116.1431    116.1423
123.0542    123.0542
123.0549    123.0542

input_csv <- structure(list(Col = c(116.1423, 116.1431, 116.1431, 116.1431, 
123.0542, 123.0549), NewCol = c(116.1423, 116.1423, 116.1423, 
116.1423, 123.0542, 123.0542)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

if (taken the last row for example) `123.0542>116.1423+116.1423*tolerance`.
`tolerance <- as.double(0.00001)`
Without data.table I've solved it with the code bellow:

````
output[i] <- ifelse((as.double(input_csv[i, "Col"]) > as.double(output[i - 1]) + tolerance * output[i - 1]),
                      input_csv[i, "Col"],
                      output[i - 1])
input_csv$newCol<- output```
````

Comment: Can you please describe in words what your goal is with the code? And when you say it "does not work as I imagine", how do you mean? Do you get an error or warnings? A different result than expected? What is wrong with it?

Comment: I'm trying to normalize the values from Col - if they are in a certain tolerance. Does not work as I imagine means the shift/lag/lead does not return me the newCol value from "row above".

Comment: You use `newCol` in your definition of `newCol`... does it already exist and you are updating it? Or are you trying to create `newCol` based on `Col` only? (It would be nice if you used consistent capitalization between `newCol` (in your code) and `NewCol` (in your sample data).)

Comment: I also think your diagnosis of the problem is bad. `shift` works just fine. We can break it down into steps to see what is happening: `input_csv[,
  shifted_new_col := shift(NewCol)][,
  with_tol := shifted_new_col * (1 + tolerance)][,
  test := Col > with_tol][,
  result := ifelse(test, Col, shifted_new_col)
]`. Run that, look at the result, and tell me what is wrong. (Or is is right?) We can fill in the `NA` with the `fill` argument of `shift`...

Comment: `ifelse` won't work to compare a column *as you're updating it*. Your `for` loop solution will. There might be a more clever solution, however, which could be faster than the for loop. Something like multiplying `Col` by 1 + tolerance to get a threshold, looking to see the first row to exceed the threshold, and repeating.

Comment: I think `shift` is a red herring, however. You don't actually want to compare a value to the previous row---and you should edit your question to make that clear. `shift` works great for comparing the value in the previous row. Rather, you are comparing values to a fixed row until a threshold is achieved. You compare row 2 to row 1. Then you compare row 3 to row 1 (not to row 2). Then you compare row 4 to row 1. Then you compare row 5 to row 1, and finally see a difference, and now row 5 is your comparison row.

Comment: The way I thought about it: I sort Col and copy the 1st value (lowest) to NewCol. Then I loop with ifelse and compare the 2nd value of Col with 1st value of NewCol + tol*1st value of NewCol. If the threshold is not met, 2nd value of NewCol is equal with 1st value of NewCol. 3rd value of Col is compared with 2nd value of NewCol and so on. Another way I've tried (with same result) is to compare the value from Col to the max(NewCol)+tol*max(NewCol) as I'm going ascending. Still, it produces the same incorrect result.

Comment: the max solution is not working because it's still using a col I'm updating.

Comment: In the end I've extracted the column in a vector and run a standard for loop over it while keeping an external reference variable. Ran a performance test and haven't noticed any performance degradation so I'll stick to this solution.